# how to change SQL column type in visual studio C#

Tags: c#, sql, database

I made a C# Program with sql database,
after finishing the program and start working on it I want to change one of the columns type from int to nvarchar(50), knowing that the database had been filled with data.

I changed the table column type to nvarchar(50), and change it also on the dataset to System.String.
After Running the program it gives me this exception

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.FormatException: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed, Boolean& typeChanged, Boolean allowStreaming)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Tiryaq.TiryaqDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(TiryaqDatabaseDataSet dataSet) in C:\Users\Firas\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Tiryaq\Tiryaq\TiryaqDatabaseDataSet.Designer.cs:line 1973
   at Tiryaq.Form1.medicinTableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Firas\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Tiryaq\Tiryaq\Form1.cs:line 31
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

thank you.

UPDATE : actually the exception rise when clicking the save button
here is the method

```
private void medicinTableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            {
                this.Validate();
                this.medicinTableBindingSource.EndEdit();
                this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.tiryaqDatabaseDataSet);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you refresh the dataset? `TiryaqDatabaseDataSet`?

Comment: I'm not sure, how to do it ??

Comment: Try open it up and right-click somewhere on the area that is opened and see if there's an option to refresh the schema.

Comment: there isn't, but I tried to restart visual studio befor

Comment: It's likely that the dataset isn't updated completely. Try re-generating it?

Comment: I did a refresh to it but nothing happend

Comment: Please show the problematic codes, and it will be helpful if you can display the table structure

Comment: Have you used that column in where clause? If so, you need to change parameter collection in where clause too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it,
after changing the type in the database and the dataset, I must open `Datasetname.Designer.cs` and look for all the `column_name values` and change them to `string` because not all the code will be changed after changing the type in the database and the dataset.
thank you guys for your help.